# How to get rid of space above header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to eliminate the gap above my header in which I have an drop down menu button box, and my h1 header below it.

How do I get rid of this space?

I have tried setting the margins to 0 on the body, html, button navigation bar, and the h1 inside of my header, none of these solutions worked.

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: rgb(45, 22, 6);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #3d594b;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

h1#header-title {
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <button class="dropbtn">Menu navigation</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="index.html">Home Page</a>
      <a href="Links\1">1</a>
      <a href="2">2</a>
      <a href="3">3</a>
      <a href="Links\4">4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 id="header-title">Page Example</h1>
</header>
```

I expected the space above the header to be gone.

Comment: Which space are you talking about? can you please share the screenshots?

Comment: can't see the space either, it's probably in a portion of the code you have not added to your questions. please post the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time and replies. I found the problem... There was a character before my link tag for the style sheet. I deleted that and the problem was solved. Sorry I missed it and posted the problem! *Face-Palm*